# M/M/1 queueing system with random dropping customers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, poisson-process, queueing-theory

I have an M/M/1 queueing system in which customers arrives at rate $\lambda$ and are served at rate $\mu$, but, upon entry, each customer can be randomly dropped with probability $1-p$ or enter the queue with probability $p$, indipendently from queue state or any other system variable.
[image: M/M/1 with random dropping]

How can I find the probability that, in a time interval of length $T$, no packets are being dropped?

Comment: This is just a split Poisson process, so the probability would be $e^{-\lambda(1-p)T}$.

Comment: Thanks @Math1000. So the probability that no packets are being dropped in a time interval $T$ would be $1 - e^{-\lambda(1-p)T}$, right?

Comment: For a fixed $\lambda$ and $p$ the probability should definitely converge to zero as $T\to\infty$...

Comment: Ok, so I have: $P[N = 0] = e^{-\lambda(1-p)T}[\lambda(1-p)T]^0/0!$, which lead to your first answer... correct?

Comment: Yes. Again, this is a simple question on Poisson processes, and the queue itself is irrelevant here.